# removing object from game in Java (eclipse)

Tags: java, eclipse, class, object, handler

lets get right into it, i have a 'handler' class which is full of getters and setters and it includes in it code which adds and removes object, it looks like this:

```
public void addObject(GameObject object){
    this.object.add(object);
}
public void removeObject(GameObject object){
    this.object.remove(object);
```

Note that 'GameObject' is a class and all objects extend that class 
And then i create an object here,

```
if(mouseOver(mx, my, 840/2-100, 149, 200, 64)){
        game.gameState = STATE.Game;
        handler.addObject(new Player(0, 300, ID.Player,game.playerImg, game));
        handler.addObject(new BasicEnemy(700, 300, ID.BasicEnemy, game.enemyImg, game));
        handler.addObject(new F1Jutsu(400, 300, ID.F1Jutsu, game.f1jutsuImg, game));
    }
```

The stuff inside parameters are the parameters of the object I want to add. Each object is its own class of course. Now i want to remove the object F1Jutsu if it's x value is outside the game, and the object moves to the right every second (which works so i wont paste it here, will do if asked)

```
        if(x > 800){
        handler.removeObject(this);
    }
```

I have this inside a 'tick' function (inside the F1Jutsu class) which is like a run function. The problem is, that as soon the removeObject method is called i get a nullpointer exception, the following error:

```
Exception in thread "Thread-2" java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.ninja.main.F1Jutsu.tick(F1Jutsu.java:24)
at com.ninja.main.Handler.tick(Handler.java:14)
at com.ninja.main.Game.tick(Game.java:110)
at com.ninja.main.Game.run(Game.java:87)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Basically, there is a NullPointerException (im removing a null?? but its an object) at the F1Jutsu class where it is being told to remove object, and then every place which is calling the remove object method and everywhere that is calling the place calling the remove object etc. is put causing an error. 
I think the idea might be that the object's x value is null now which is the nullpointer(?) but not sure, and if so how would i fix this? 
 Im sorry for the long post (potato?) 
 EDIT:

line 24 of F1Jutsu is:

```
if(x > 800){
        handler.removeObject(this);
    }
```

MRK im not sure what you mean, i included the part where im adding the object and where im removing in the code above. 
 
EDIT: 
Okay, after much work i have come to the conclusion that when i add the object it is added as a null image. I must ask how do i set it to something (that is not null) without changing the basis of my code (the parameters)

Comment: "*im removing a null?? but its an object*" - Objects *can* be `null`.

Comment: why don't you just debug and see what is null? or just check for null, if(object!=null) remove..

Comment: What is F1Jutsu.java line 24?

Comment: exactly what I was 'bout to ask

Comment: have you overriden equals and hashCode or else java guesses what those values are and you'll have no control, Im guessing your adding child objects to a list, when trying to remove those objects it cannot be found since the childobject is not defined. in exampel you might have different class members in child class but when adding you add the super class. upon removal from the handler thechild is not defined?? maybe?

Comment: @Maroun i know objects can be null, what i meant was that im removing the object and it is an object because i added an object above and im trying to remove that same object

Comment: Debugging is the best way to detect what is null. Without watching the full code, we are speculating

Comment: @GMagician, can you please debug and verify whether `handler` is not null at line 24

Comment: im not sure how to do that, but i believe that handler is not null it is the actual object that i am accessing; more to the point the solution below worked perfectly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't be calling the remove method in the middle of a block of code in the object your are removint; even though it is removed it will attempt to finish the code but will fail because all of it's variables would then be `null`. To fix this error, I suggest adding a `boolean` called `removed` in your `GameObject` class. Instead of calling `handler.removeObject(this)` simply set `removed` equal to `true`. You then need to add a few lines of code in your `Handler` class in the `tick()` method to check for and remove all objects with a `removed` value of `true`. Something like this

```
for (int i = 0; i < object.size(); i++) {
     if (object.get(i).removed)
          object.remove(i);
}
```