# How do I delete objects in a Java game

Tags: java, awt, java-2d

I have a object in my java game which is going to be a coin, currently its just a rect made with

```
g.setColor(Color.yellow);
g.fillRect(x, y, 16, 16);
```

I have collisions set up to give the player points when they touch it, and that works fine, but how do I make it delete itself after its touched? as it is the points just keep going up.

The only thing I could think of was to recolor it to make it look like it wasn't there, but thats far from the same thing.

Comment: We need *way* more context than this to give you an answer.

Comment: One way you could do it is to just move the object's coordinates off of the game map.

Comment: `if(!hasPlayerTouchedObjectYet)`

Comment: (Note that your object never "existed" to start with. If you want to not draw it on the screen, all you have to do is not draw it on the screen)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should have a `Rectangle` class, or rather a `Coin` class, e.g.

```
public class Coin {
    int xPos;
    int yPos;
    int width;
    int height;

    // For giving player points
    int points;

    // Constructors, etc
    // e.g. public int getXPos(), public int getYPos()..
}
```

At the start, you will have something like an `ArrayList` of `Coin`, e.g.

```
ArrayList<Coin> coins = new ArrayList<Coin>();
```

In your drawing method,

```
for (Coin c : coins) {
    g.fillOval(c.getXPos(), c.getYPos(), c.getWidth(), c.getHeight());
}
```

When the player collides with the `Coin`, you'll just need to remove it from the `ArrayList`.

To make it more extensible, you can even define an interface `Collectible`, and make all your collectible in-game objects such as `Coin` in this case implement the `Collectible` interface.

Answer (score 1):

You really should have an `ArrayList` of objects in some kind of level or handler `class` to deal with having multiple objects. That way you can easily `add` or `remove` them as you need to using the `ArrayList` functions `add()` and `remove()`. For more specific information on actually removing objects see this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30420793/removing-object-from-game-in-java-eclipse/30430905#30430905). And for information on handling objects in a game see this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30443458/spawning-mutiple-circles-and-make-them-move/30443968#30443968).

Answer (score 0):

If you made an object you could make it equal to null.

```
rectObj = null;
```

If you simply did a fillRect() method without making an actual object you could move it off the panel or simply color it white. However, I hope that you did use an object as it would be a lot simpler and effective.